# ¿Cómo detectar si esta corriendo un sistema virtualizado?

Tags: linux, windows, virtualización

trabajo con varias personas accesando a sus escritorios de manera remota, por la naturaleza del trabajo me interesa saber si lo que estoy viendo es una maquina virtual, para prevenir ciertas cosas delicadas. Uso linux con tiger/reminna para conectar a otros escritorios windows o linux, pero me interesa detectar si me estoy conectando a una maquina física o virtualizada.

Comment: Un sirvedor que mantengo es virualizado.  Veo a Device Manager dentro de System Devices y tiene devices de VMWare.  Es posible que VirtualBox y  Windows tiene algo semejante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**En linux** puedes hacerlo utlizando el comando hostnamectl,

```
hostnamectl status
```

Obtendrás los datos del equipo donde Chasis te dirá si es desktop, laptop, o virtualizado, algo cómo esto:

```
 Icon name: computer-laptop
 Chassis: laptop
 Machine ID: 84e3c8e37e114ac9bc9f69689b49cfaa
```

**En windows** puedes hacerlo utilizando el comando SYSTEMINFO en CMD,  en caso de ser

```
SYSTEMINFO
```

obtendrías un resultado similar a ésto:

```
System Manufacturer:       VMware, Inc.
System Model:              VMware Virtual Platform
```

Comment: Las salidas de los comandos que amablemente me muestras pueden ser alteradas? precisamente para sobrepasar una revisión de este tipo.

Comment: No estoy del todo seguro de eso, pero yo creería que si es posible cambiar ciertos datos de ese output no sé si todos, haría falta googlear un poco..

Comment: en sistemas systemd `$ hostnamectl set-chassis server` cambia el status